# Storing date periods in database

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, period

I would like to discuss the "best" way to storage date periods in a database. Let's talk about SQL/MySQL, but this question may be for any database. I have the sensation I am doing something wrong for years...

In english, the information I have is:

```
-In year 2014, value is 1000
-In year 2015, value is 2000
-In year 2016, there is no value
-In year 2017 (and go on), value is 3000
```

Someone may store as:

```
BeginDate   EndDate     Value
2014-01-01  2014-12-31  1000
2015-01-01  2015-12-31  2000
2017-01-01  NULL        3000
```

Others may store as:

```
Date        Value
2014-01-01  1000
2015-01-01  2000
2016-01-01  NULL
2017-01-01  3000
```

- First method validation rules looks like mayhem to develop in order to avoid holes and overlaps.
- In second method the problem seem to filter one punctual date inside a period.

What my colleagues prefer? Any other suggestion?

**EDIT:** I used full year only for example, my data usually change with day granularity.

**EDIT 2:** I thought about using stored "Date" as "BeginDate", order rows by Date, then select the "EndDate" in next (or previous) row. Storing "BeginDate" and "Interval" would lead to hole/overlap problem as method one, that I need a complex validation rule to avoid.

Comment: You can store only year like `2015`,`2016` etc

Comment: If the information you need to store is just a year, why not just an integer to store the year and the value field? Always keep it simple.

Comment: Both methods are acceptable - as is the suggestion by Sadikhasan (and echoed by Jorge Campos)

Comment: I used full year only for example, my data usually change with day granularity.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on the way you will be using this information - I'm assuming you do more than just store values for a year in your database.

Lots of guesses here, but I guess you have other tables with time-bounded data, and that you need to compare the dates to find matches.

For instance, in your current schema:

```
select *
from other_table ot
inner join year_table yt on ot.transaction_date between yt.year_start and yt.year_end
```

That should be an easy query to optimize - it's a straight data comparison, and if the table is big enough, you can add indexes to speed it up.

In your second schema suggestion, it's not as easy:

```
select *
from other_table ot
inner join year_table yt 
 on ot.transaction_date between yt.year_start 
 and yt.year_start + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

Crucially - this is harder to optimize, as every comparison needs to execute a scalar function. It might not matter - but with a large table, or a more complex query, it could be a bottleneck.

You can also store the year as an integer (as some of the commenters recommend).

```
select *
from other_table ot
inner join year_table yt on year(ot.transaction_date) = yt.year
```

Again - this is likely to have a performance impact, as every comparison requires a function to execute.

The purist in me doesn't like to store this as an integer - so you could also use MySQL's [YEAR datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/year.html).

So, assuming data size isn't an issue you're optimizing for, the solution really would lie in the way your data in this table relates to the rest of your schema.

Comment: I thought in second method to not store a interval (days, years, or another timespan) to avoid hole/overlap problem. Maybe you could order rows by Date, then select the "EndDate" in next (or previous) row. I know, this doesn't seem efficient either.